# Is it possible to get to know which tab it opens in ("window.open('_blank');" in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, browser

I want to execute the following code on my driver using Selenium:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('{0}', '_blank');".format(player_url))
```

However, at the same time, I want to track which tab it opens up. I'm going to open so many tabs simultaneously, and it is very difficult to track which tab it opens in my hand. But `driver.execute_script()` does not let me know it. And other functions also try to open up a new window.

So is it possible to know which tab it opens up?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get some unique identifier for each opened tab to be able to handle it after all tabs were opened?

Comment: @Andersson Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement something like below:

```
players = [player_url_1, player_url_2, player_url_3]

windows = {}
current = driver.current_window_handle

for player_url in players:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('{0}', '_blank');".format(player_url))
    new_window = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current and window not in windows.values()][0]
    windows[player_url] = new_window
```

After you opened all windows `windows` should look like:

```
{player_url_1: 'CDwindow-XXX', player_url_2: 'CDwindow-YYY', player_url_3: 'CDwindow-ZZZ'}
```

so you get dictionary of *"URL_of_page"*: *"ID_of_tab"* pairs

Comment: Thanks but doesn't it have a chance that there are multiple windows added into `driver.window_handles` if the `window.open()` is called from more than one places? IOW I fear another `driver.execute_script(...)` is called just after one `driver.execute_script(...)` but before the `new_window = [window for ...`.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Do you mean that `window.open()` is triggered automatically by some JavaScript that you cannot control?

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the list of window handles before you execute that method, execute the method, and then grab the list of window handles again. Write a method that you pass the before and after lists of handles to that determines which handle is new and returns it. Assign that return to a variable and you can reference it as needed.